# RTC Server Integration BF Server

Tags: rtc, buildforge

I am trying to integrate RTC server with BF Server for continuous integration of projects using ant scripts.
But somehow I am not able to connect them together.

I am refering this tutorial as a reference
https://jazz.net/library/article/607

Some information about my config :

1. RTC Server running on : 8.X.X.1
2. BF Server running on  :8.X.X.2
3. BF agent running on : 8.X.X.3

   Can anybody point me any tutorial or link for reference.

In reference to the above mentioned tutorial link , I have some questions.

Qns 1: In the tutorial I am not able to find out where ANT should be installed ?

Qns 2: Is RTC and JAZZ Source control are same thing ?

Qns 3: From the tutorial it is saying I have to use buildtoolkit , and its location is /jazz/buildsystem/buildtoolkit. But somehow I am not able to figure out `rtc_install_Path`. Can anybody help me in finding out the default location of RTC Install Path.

Qns 4 : What and How to configure RTC so that it can trigger the build in BF server as soon as some new code is checked in ?

Any help is appreciated.

**Update :** 
I found answers for Qns 1 and Qns 3 , but for 2 and 4 , I am still searching

Comment: If you could ask this question again at http://jazz.net/forum, you will reach several experts on this topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ans 1 : Ant should be installed on the BF agent.

Ans 3 : When you install the buildtoolkit on the BF agent it will create a directory structure something like this `/jazz/buildsystem/buildtoolkit` under `/opt/IBM`.

Ans 4 :From the eclipse RTC client I have to schedule the build on a time basis(e.g every 60 mins) and after this it will check in every 60 mins for the new code checked in and trigger the build if there is any new code checked in last 60 mins.

Build Forge is not that smart that it can initiate the build as soon as somecode is checked in ,contrary it waits on the scheduled time to initiate the build.

Answer (score 1):

Qns 2: Is RTC and JAZZ Source control are same thing ?

Ans 2: Jazz Source Control (Jazz SCM) is part of RTC. RTC has also additional capabilities like working on workitems, plans etc.

For 4 I would reccommend you asking on jazz.net forum.